# How to download jQuery Data Table As Excel File

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor-pages

i have jQuery Data table loaded by Asp controller and Js file i need to download all data in table as excel file by clicking abutton as shown in attached image

below my html code

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Download As Exel"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a asp-page="Createe" class="btn btn-info">Add</a>
        </div>

    </div>
   
<br />
    <table id="DT_load" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>T-Date</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>QTY</th>
                <th>ExP</th>
                <th>Person</th>
                <th>Cat</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>How</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/js/Expiree.js"></script>
}
```

my controller is

```
namespace Elwady.Controllers
{
    [Route("/api/ex")]
    [ApiController]
    public class Expirelast : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public Expirelast(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            return Json(new { data = await _db.Expiree.ToListAsync() });
        }
        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var bookFromdb = await _db.Expiree.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
            if (bookFromdb == null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error While Deleting" });

            }
            _db.Expiree.Remove(bookFromdb);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete Successful" });

        }
    }
}
```

my Js file

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/ex",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row) { return '<span>' + row.transDate.split('T')[0] + '</span>' },
                "name": "Transaction Date", "width": "7%",
            },
            { "data": "itemName", "width": "18%" },
            { "data": "itemPrice", "width": ".5%" },
            { "data": "itemQ", "width": ".5%" },
            { "data": "expireDate", "width": "1%" },
            { "data": "person", "width": "1%" },
            { "data": "category", "width": ".25%" },
            { "data": "status", "width": ".25%" },
            { "data": "how", "width": "1%" },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row) { return '<span>' + row.exitDate.split('T')[0] + '</span>' },
                "name": "Exit date", "width": "7%",
            },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
                        <a href="/Expire/Edit?id=${data}" class='text-primary' style='cursor:pointer; width:40px;'>
                          Edit
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a class='text-danger' style='cursor:pointer; width:40px;'
                          onclick=Delete('/api/ex?id='+${data})>
                        Delete
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;
                          <a href="/Expire/Exit?id=${data}" class='text-success' style='cursor:pointer; width:40px;'>
                           Exit
                        </a>
                        </div>`;
                },
                "width": "8%",
                "orderable": false
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "no data found"
        },
        "width": "100%"
    });
}
function Delete(url) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true
    }).then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        toastr.success(data.message);
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

image to view my UI
[image]

i searched for more than one time to get best solution but i failed to get the best solution

Comment: Have you looked at SheetJS ? https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs
If you a JSON array object, you can easily export it with this library

Comment: i tried to get the solution but no result can you support with direct solution according attached code as i am fresh Asp.net with zero experience in jQuery